# Winforms application crashes

Tags: c#, winforms, crash, process, diagnostics

I am developing an application in Visual C# using winforms.

The application is basically a screen with three tabs. *It shows values from processes running on the system per second* (using `System.Diagnostics.Process[]` ).

It generates and updates lot of numbers and calculations (around 4000/second). But after 10000 iterations or ~45 minutes of work, it just crashes and the amazing part is It always crashes around the same time.

The RAM involved here is just 70mb and CPU load never goes above 35% for the app under windows xp and windows 7. The aim of the app is to allow users to view processes running on the system with the cpuload and memory load. we cannot suggest taskmanager due to security reasons.

The error is not trapped by C# by any of the `try - catch` methods

Following screens are a sample that follow after the crash

[image]

The main application screen looks like this

[image]

Has anybody faced such a situation where the app crashes after a fixed run length.

**Please suggest a diagnostic tool or a method to trap such errors.**

Thanks for the replies

Comment: Have you checked for any memory leaks ? and do you have any code smaple ?

Comment: it is just a timer that runs a infinite loop that gets all processes and shows in a grid. like do {  Process[] plist = Process.GetProcesses();     } while(true); Memory leak (even larger applications run fine, plus it always crashes after a fixed run) . BTW your blog at wordpress is good.

Comment: With timer you don't mean the timer object right, have you tried using the timer object instead of using an infinite loop.  Thnx i try to update my blog as much as i can

Comment: and do you also use threading for example a backgroundworker

Comment: It is hard to say what is the cause. if it crashes after specefic itteration then it mihgt be some out of array index or something. paste some of the code you think it might be the problem, specially yout timier code

Comment: Does the same happen when you have the debugger attached?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lexli/archive/2009/08/23/when-the-application-program-crashes-on-windows.aspx

Comment: the link mentioned above has changed to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this into your service in the main void

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

        public static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            // do your logging here, write to a file, or send an email
        }
```

and

```
service.ExceptionThrown += service_ExceptionThrown;

        private static void service_ExceptionThrown(object sender, ExceptionThrownEventArgs e)
        {
            // do your logging here, write to a file, or send an email
        }
```

and if you want to debug your service in visual studio then just add -d by start up option in the Command line arguments

[image: Command line argumnets]

Comment: @johnblade :  i used a timer the loop just loops over all the processes like foreach(Process p in plist) { } . Yes i tried using backgroundworker as well. and even put thread.sleep(1000) just to slow it down a bit. Are there any tools that just point in some way to the errors. I have downloaded the CLR profiler, but oh god it looks one needs a whole week to operate it. (there aren't any data saves or data tables)

Comment: Are you able to get it to run in visual studio with the -d argument ?

Comment: i have set the -d option and do i need to run it within visual studio . I will place the event handlers (i think i need to place them in program.cs)

Comment: my events are in the static main function, add them there

Comment: it seems to be all-right when it is run from visual studio, it is just total confusion now. and crashes when run standalone. i guess i will run more tests. i wish i had a magic wand or a jinn

Comment: i have marked it as answer because, it has set the track for me to diagnose more. I would recommend http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798 Application that seems to be helpful. thanx to all for replies

Answer (score 4):

If you have Visual Studio installed on this machine, you should be able to debug the application, when it crashes. At least you should see which exception is thrown and where.

In my application I have a handler, which catches uncatched exceptions and writes them to a logfile.

Add to the constructor

```
AppDomain currDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExHandler);
```

and add also this handler

```
private void UnhandledExHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    // Log the exception here
}
```

Comment: i will try it with debugger on.